# How to reference the GitHub Pages URL in a GitHub action?

Tags: github-actions, github-pages

I'm writing a github action that generates some content on the side. It contains the following step:

```yaml
- name: Generate a client-side redirect on the index page
  run: sed -i '19i\      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://casey-hofland.github.io/UnityClock/manual/'">' _site/index.html
```

This github action needs to be generic, so I need to change this line:
`URL='https://casey-hofland.github.io/UnityClock/manual/'`
To something like:
`URL='{{ $GITHUB_PAGES_URL }}manual/'`

I've looked through the [default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) and haven't found anything like it, is there any way for me to retrieve the link?

Note: it still has to work when people are using a custom github pages link, so doing some wizardry like `{{ $GITHUB_ACCOUNT_NAME }}/{{ $GITHUB_REPO_NAME }}` is not an option.

---

Bonus:

I'm kind of a github actions / bash noob so any tips on how to implement a variable inside my `sed -i` command would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GitHub Pages site is available via the APIs, for example REST (see the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pages?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-github-pages-site)). You can get it in a `run` step using the GitHub CLI:

```yaml
- name: Generate redirect
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  run: |
    url=$(gh api "repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/pages" --jq '.html_url')
    sed -i '19i\
          <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='"$url"manual/'">
    ' _site/index.html
```

This takes into consideration everything like protocol and custom domain names.

Comment: It was missing a closing bracket ) - but wow, that just worked! I have no idea what this code even does so I'm really thankful for it ^_^